# Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment (change css background-color)

Tags: javascript, css

It's register page. I try to write something about Form validation.

I want to get the "em1" , and change it's color (to hightlight) when inputed password > 0 , to show register that his/her password is too weak.

but I don't know why the error happends, here is my code:

```js
var em1 = document.getElementById("em1");
var em2 = document.getElementById("em2");
var em3 = document.getElementById("em3");

pass_input.onkeyup = function() {
  if (this.value.length > 0) {
    em1.style.background - color = "yellow";
  }
}
```

```css
#pass_em {
  opacity: 0.5;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
#em1 {
  width: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
#em2 {
  width: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
#em3 {
  width: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td class="tag">password：</td>
  <td>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />

    <div id="pass_em">
      <em id="em1">weak</em>
      <em id="em2">soso</em>
      <em id="em3">okey</em>
    </div>
    <span id="password_tip" style="color:red;">*</span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I guess it happends due to my method to change "em1"'s "background-color",
is it?

Comment: `em1.style.backgroundColor`

Comment: `em1.style.background - color = "yellow";` - this is invalid(-ish)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
em1.style.background - color = "yellow";
```

This is the right syntax:

```
em1.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
```

Comment: It's not working for me